# top-left corner icon on a dialog from resources in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, resources, icons

thank you in advance.

I'm developing an application in Win32 C++ which its main window comes up from a resource file because it's easier to place controls.

to that I use CreateDialog a statement

The problem is, I don't achieve to put it an Icon such as I could with CreateWindow statement at the WNDCLASSEX sctructure.

does somebody know the way to get a dialog with that top-left-corner Icon?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can enable your application to display an icon in the title bar of a dialog box by adding the `WS_SYSMENU` and `WS_CAPTION` styles to the dialog box template and sending the `WM_SETICON` message from within the dialog box procedure in response to the `WM_INITDIALOG` message.

Answer (score 1):

`CreateDialog` returns the window handle of the dialog. Send that window [`WM_SETICON`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632643.aspx) messages to specify the icon for the window. Or indeed send the messages in response to [`WM_INITDIALOG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645428.aspx).